# createElement img with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, createelement

It does not show any image on the browser, I wonder where it goes wrong in creating the image? I had made a variable `imgFace` where `i` store the image and make the right properties for it but it does not seem to show anything.

Here is my code:

```js
var numberOfFaces = 5;
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("LeftSide");

function generateFaces() {
  var count = 0;
  while (count <= numberOfFaces) {
    var imgFace = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
    var random_nr = Math.random() * 400;
    random_nr = Math.floor(random_nr);
    imgFace.style.top = random_nr + "px";
    imgFace.style.left = random_nr + "px";
    theLeftSide.appendChild(imgFace);
    count++;

  }
}
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#RightSide {
  left: 500px;
  border-left: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<body onload="generateFaces()">
  <h1>Matching Game</h1>
  <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>
  <div id="LeftSide">
  </div>
  <div id="RightSide">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: As Sebastian suggest, `img.src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";` should be `imgFace.src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";`

Comment: still not working tho.

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateFaces() {
        var count = 0;
        while(count <= numberOfFaces){
            var imgFace = document.createElement("img");
            imgFace.src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
            var random_nr = Math.random() * 400;
            random_nr = Math.floor(random_nr);
            imgFace.style.top = random_nr + "px";
            imgFace.style.left = random_nr + "px";
            theLeftSide.appendChild(imgFace);
            count++;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
img.src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
```

with

```
imgFace.src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
```

NOTE: `img` is not the correct variable name you have defined. It should be `imgFace`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things,

1. You had `img.src` which should be `imgFace.src`.
2. You didn't call your `generateFaces` function.

```js
var numberOfFaces = 5;
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("LeftSide");

function generateFaces() {
  var count = 0;
  while (count <= numberOfFaces) {
    var imgFace = document.createElement("img");
    imgFace.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
    var random_nr = Math.random() * 400;
    random_nr = Math.floor(random_nr);
    imgFace.style.top = random_nr + "px";
    imgFace.style.left = random_nr + "px";
    theLeftSide.appendChild(imgFace);
    count++;

  }
}

generateFaces();
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#RightSide {
  left: 500px;
  border-left: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<h1>Matching Game</h1>
<p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>
<div id="LeftSide">
</div>
<div id="RightSide">
</div>
```

*[External example](https://jsfiddle.net/AdityaParab/rxycL1vh/2/)*

Comment: `generateFaces ` called on onload :  `<body onload="generateFaces()">`.